# Python Imaging Library Resave Image

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

Suppose I have already saved an image in JPEG format and quality 90 using PIL. If I load this image and try to save it again do I need to specify quality 100 this time so that the image will not be further compressed or does PIL recognize that the image is in quality 90 format and saves it without more compression?

I have this question because I want to save all my images in an LMDB file. I have the images saved in the disk with 90 JPEG compression and wonder if the following snippet

```
    img = Image.open(imagePath)
    faux_file = BytesIO()
    img.save(faux_file, 'JPEG')
    contents = faux_file.getvalue()
    faux_file.close()
```

will further downgrade the image (which I do not want to happen).

Comment: It's a decent question. But did you try and see what happens?

Comment: You are right I should have checked it first ! From what I saw the image that is saved is different in size and smaller so I assume that the image is further downgraded !

Comment: Then (I'm guessing here) PIL always decompresses the original, so the existing compression data is lost. Best thing would be to save with the best *possible* quality, so nothing new gets lost (or rather, as little as possible). But here is a thought: opening the image and savin it under another name is equivalent to *copying* it. Why don't you try that instead?

Comment: Yes I think that would be the best approach since the existing compression data is lost.